# char pointer parameter different behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, function-calls

I have the following code:

```
void uppercase(char *sir)
{

for(int i=0;i<strlen(sir);i++)
{

 sir[i]=(char)toupper(sir[i]);
}
} 


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

//char  lower[]="u forgot the funny"; this works
//char  *lower="u forgot the funny";  this gives me a runtime error

uppercase(lower);

cout<<lower<<"\n\n";

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

I have noted that if I run with the char vector it works.
When I try to run with the second method it generates a runtime error.
I would like to know the reason for this behaviour please.

Comment: A real C++ compiler shouldn't even *compile* the second case.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  In C++11, I would agree.  But in C++03, I believe this will compile and be well-defined -- which is not to say what the programmer might expect!

Comment: @KerrekSB clang on osx just givves a warning `conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]`

Comment: Turn your warnings on and make the code compile with no warnings. Warnings are logical errors in your thinking.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Oh right, I forget that this used to be different. I mean, the literal has always been a const char array, right? It's only the conversion that used to be allowed?

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Correct.  Even tho the pointer is not `const`, modifying the values pointed to would evoke Undefined Behavior -- but the compiler would allow the initialization of the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify string literals; doing so (as in your second case) is undefined behaviour.

```
char x[] = "foo";
```

creates a character array containing the characters `f,o,o,\0`. It's basically a mutable copy of the string.

```
char *x = "foo";
```

creates a string pointer pointing to the `"foo"` string literal. The literal may live in some read-only memory, in the program memory, or in a constant pool. Writing to it is undefined behaviour. Also, not that the type of a string literal is always `const char[]`, so assigning it to a `char *` is violating const-correctness.

Comment: +1 but note:  the `char*` example will no longer even compile under C++11.

Comment: As nneonneo said, the latter don't work because you can't convert const string literal to non-const char *. That being said, adding 'const' before 'char *x = "foo";' will work.

Answer (score 1):

The former creates a character array which can be mutated, the latter is a pointer to fixed memory (which cannot be manipulated)